# Conditions for a ring $R$ such that every subring is an ideal.

Tags: ring-theory, ideals

In class we learn that every ideal of $\mathbb Z$ is of the form $n \mathbb Z$ where $n \in \mathbb Z$ so every subring is an ideal . So I wonder "what conditions does an arbitrary ring $R$ need to satisfy so that every subring is an ideal?"

My teacher suggest that I need to start with a commutative ring with identity. Then I found that the only ring with that property has to be isomorphic to $\mathbb Z$ or $\mathbb Z / n \mathbb Z$.

So what about a commutative ring without identity? or a non-commutative ring?

Comment: Mind if you share your results about commutative rings with 1?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2262859/ring-such-that-every-subring-is-an-ideal/2263647#2263647    In this question they talk about it

Comment: Also I think $R = \mathbb{Z}/(p)$ works for every prime number $p$, because if a subring contains any $n \neq 0$, it contains 1 and hence all of $R$.

Comment: Yes @red_trumpet, but what about the general case? $\mathbb Z /(p)$ has identity and it's commutative

Comment: Notice that the ring $n \mathbb{Z}$ for $n > 1$, which is a ring without identity, has this property as well.

Comment: What's the definition of "subring" in your textbook?

Comment: @DavidR. A subring $S$ of a ring it's a nonempty subset such that $(S,+)$ it's an abelian group and for every $a,b \in S$ then $a*b \in S$